# Two API's inter connection is possible in android?

Tags: android, api

if save button clicked the selected values should be saved in first api.then back to product add to cart page, before selected values available in that page.is it possible in e-Commerce android mobile apps.

Comment: Can u please explain it briefly?

Comment: i have ecommerce app.it work like,it having two pages.first page is product option choosen page.(like height,width...)this choosen details save one json api.then second page to add to cart page.it automatically retrieve data from another json api,those selected options are available in this page.but i checked it in coding.coding doesn't pass any values in those two activities.then how data will be send & receieve it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: do you know the answer? @Mat

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I think you mean "how to pass data between two activities".

Activities are java classes, but you usually don't use them via constructor. Instead of that, we use what we call an intent: a generic builder which allows us to send zero or many arguments to the activity class, using what we call a Bundle, a datatype very similar to a Map. So, to communicate the first activity with the second, you can add the desired data to a Bundle, add that to the intent, and then, in the second activity, take the data.

Now, for this kind of fluxes, you perfectly can, and should, have a separate data storage layer which all activities can consult. And you can use compound views or fragments to avoid loading different activities for trivial tasks.

The data storage layer advice also works if you wish to combine several remote responses into one. Just make all the network communication in a separate layer, then store the results and provide the answers to the views (activities). Remember, apps are not webpages, and people expect them to work even if the internet connection fails.